# Curl request to a Kubernetes cluster type service

Tags: kubernetes, blue-green-deployment

I am trying to send a curl request to a Kubernetes ClusterType service. Is there any way to perform curl requests to service?

I am deploying an application with Blue/Green deployment. So here need to verify the Blue version is properly working or not. So decide to send a curl request to the blue version. When I get 200 status, I will route all traffic to this version.

But now am facing that send curl request to the new version(Blue version) of the application.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Lei Yang, I have no idea to send a curl request to cluster type service. I can possible to send curl request to a service

Comment: from curl's perspective, there's no difference between a node type or cluster type service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClusterIP makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType. You can read more information about services [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

As the command in the first answer doesn't work, I'm posting the working solution:

```sh
kubectl run tmp-name --rm --image nginx -i --restart=Never -- /bin/bash -c 'curl -s clusterip:port'
```

with the above command curl is working fine. You can use a service name instead of cluster IP address.

`--restart=Never` is needed for using curl like this.

`--rm` ensures the Pod is deleted when the shell exits.

###### Edited:

#### But if you want to access your ClusterIp service from the host on which you run kubectl, you can use Port Forwarding.

```sh
kubectl port-forward service/yourClusterIpServiceName 28015:yourClusterIpPort
```

You will get output like this:

```yaml
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:28015 -> yourClusterIpPort
Forwarding from [::1]:28015 -> yourClusterIpPort
```

after that you will be able to reach your ClusterIP service using this command:

```sh
curl localhost:28015
```

More information about port forwarding is on [the official documentation page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a curl request to ClusterType Service, unless you are inside the cluster, you can run a pod to do that e.g

```
kubectl run --rm --image nginx -i -- curl 'http://clusterip/'
```

This will run a temp pod  to run your command and die afterward.

Comment: It raises an error.   Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -rm

Comment: try `--rm` instead.

Comment: It is 2 - in the command

Comment: You can try this https://github.com/segmentio/kubectl-curl